# Grpc WinForms vs WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, grpc

I am trying to translate a tow project from Windows forms to WPF, both net6.0-winhdows targeted.

The Windows Forms csproj looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Google.Protobuf" Version="3.21.6" />
      <PackageReference Include="Grpc" Version="2.46.3" />
      <PackageReference Include="Grpc.Net.Client" Version="2.48.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Grpc.Tools" Version="2.48.1" PrivateAssets="All">
        <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
        <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      </PackageReference>
      <PackageReference Include="MediatR" Version="10.0.1" />
      <PackageReference Include="MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="10.0.1" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="6.0.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="6.0.1" />
    </ItemGroup>

<!--    <Target Name="Protobuf_Compile_Before_AssemblyReferences" BeforeTargets="ResolveAssemblyReferences">-->
<!--        <CallTarget Targets="_Protobuf_Compile_BeforeCsCompile" />-->
<!--    </Target>-->

    <ItemGroup>
        <Protobuf Include="../../rpc/windowtrackerservice.proto" Link="windowtrackerservice.proto" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

And the WPF one like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
        <RootNamespace>WindowTracker</RootNamespace>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Google.Protobuf" Version="3.21.7" />
        <PackageReference Include="Grpc" Version="2.46.5" />
        <PackageReference Include="Grpc.Net.Client" Version="2.49.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Grpc.Tools" Version="2.49.1">
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
    </ItemGroup>

<!--    <Target Name="Protobuf_Compile_Before_AssemblyReferences" BeforeTargets="ResolveAssemblyReferences">-->
<!--        <CallTarget Targets="_Protobuf_Compile_BeforeCsCompile" />-->
<!--    </Target>-->

    <ItemGroup>
        <Protobuf Include="../../../rpc/windowtrackerservice.proto" Link="windowtrackerservice.proto" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

The commented out snippet is something I tried without any changes. While the IDE (Jetbrains Rider) does not complain about the namespace missing in both cases, only the WinForms variant is actually compiling. The WPF app show this error:

```
  MainViewModel.cs(15, 21): [CS0234] The type or namespace name 'Rpc' does not exist in the namespace 'WindowTracker' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

I tried downgrading the dependencies, that did not help. Has someone had this error and found a solution?

Comment: The Protobuf Include path should be different?

Comment: Yes. It shows up in the editor and opens also

Comment: Ended up using a wrapper in a netframework-6.0 lib and calling that wrapper

Comment: Have you tried `<Protobuf Include="../../../rpc/windowtrackerservice.proto" Link="rpc/windowtrackerservice.proto" />` (i.e. changing the "Link" attribute to rpc/)?